# Script doesn't reset and still echos message even after "refresh" on localhost

Tags: php

I have an issue that after the "Refresh" (ctrl+r and ctrl+shift+r)  , the error message "You forgot to insert an email" doesn't disappear. I don't know what is the issue. Appreciate the help in advanced.

[image]

This is a snippet from my HTML PAGE with the forms:

```
<?php

foreach ($error as $key => $errorvalue){
    echo($errorvalue);
}

?>
```

My process script which I "require" in the HTML page.

```html
$error = array();

try
{

    if(empty($username)) {

        $error[] = "You forgot to insert a username!";

    } if(empty($email)) {


        $error[] = "You forgot to insert an email!";

    }

}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you refresh a page after you submit a from it will keep submitting it every time you refresh the page, to prevent this you can use this javasricpt code in your html codes `<head>` tags

```
<script>
    if (window.history.replaceState) {
        window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.href);
    }
</script>
```

you can look at  [this website for more information](https://www.webtrickshome.com/faq/how-to-stop-form-resubmission-on-page-refresh).

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work.  It shows both errors immediately , as the fields are already empty.  But thanks for the suggestion in general!